# Need some help writing a strategy with different positions depending on three 3 signal variables

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

Hi I'm brand new in coding, and I am getting stuck every new line of code I try to write but hey its a learning process.

I'm doing a strategy based on the MACD variables.
-MACD_Line is either positive or negative.
-Signal_Line is either positive or negative.
-Histogram is either positive or negative.

Based on the historical prices there are 6 possibilities of combined signals either: ---, -++, --+, +--, ++- or +++.

What I want to do is pre-set different position sizes depending on these 6 possible output signals.

So for example: if "---" then short 50% of equity,
if "+++" then long 100% of equity,
if "-++" then short 25% of equity.

Therefore the equity position would change after one of the initial 3 variables changes.

My attempt:

```
strategy("HIST", overlay= false, initial_capital = 1, default_qty_type= strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value= 100 )

//time inputs
startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer, defval=2014, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

endDate = input(title="End Date", type=input.integer, defval=29, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input(title="End Month", type=input.integer, defval=3, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input(title="End Year", type=input.integer, defval=2021, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear, startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

//variable
ema26= ema(close,26)
ema12= ema(close,12 )
macdl= ema12-ema26
signal= ema(macdl, 9)
hist= macdl-signal


enterLong  =  crossover(macdl,0)
enterShort =  crossunder(macdl,0)

s000 = if (hist <= 0 and macdl <= 0 and signal <=0)
s001 = if (hist > 0 and macdl <= 0 and signal <= 0)
s011 = if (hist > 0 and macdl > 0 and signal <= 0) 
s111 = if (hist > 0 and macdl > 0 and signal > 0)
s011 = if (hist <= 0 and macdl > 0 signal > 0)
s001 = if (hist <= 0 and macdl <= 0 signal > 0)




if (inDateRange and s111)
    strategy.entry(id="+", long=true)

if (inDateRange and s000)
    strategy.entry(id="-", long=false)

if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in the right direction. You'll need to finish coding all the conditions yourself. See comments in code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("HIST", overlay= false, initial_capital = 1, default_qty_type= strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value= 100 )

//time inputs
startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer, defval=2014, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

endDate = input(title="End Date", type=input.integer, defval=29, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input(title="End Month", type=input.integer, defval=3, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input(title="End Year", type=input.integer, defval=2021, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear, startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

//variable
ema26= ema(close,26)
ema12= ema(close,12 )
macdl= ema12-ema26
signal= ema(macdl, 9)
hist= macdl-signal

enterLong  =  crossover(macdl,0)
enterShort =  crossunder(macdl,0)

// Two last var names clashed with others, so used "X" in them.
s000 = hist <= 0 and macdl <= 0 and signal <= 0
s001 = hist >  0 and macdl <= 0 and signal <= 0
s011 = hist >  0 and macdl >  0 and signal <= 0
s111 = hist >  0 and macdl >  0 and signal >  0
s01X = hist <= 0 and macdl >  0 and signal >  0
s00X = hist <= 0 and macdl <= 0 and signal >  0

// Detect changes in conditions.
f_changeIn(_cond) => _cond and not _cond[1]
c000 = f_changeIn(s000)
c001 = f_changeIn(s001)
c011 = f_changeIn(s011)
c111 = f_changeIn(s111)
c01X = f_changeIn(s01X)
c00X = f_changeIn(s00X)

// Functions calculates position size from a % (0 - 1.0).
f_positionSize(_percentEquity) => strategy.equity * _percentEquity / close

// Generate orders on trasitions into conditions.
float positionSize = na
if inDateRange
    if c000
        positionSize := f_positionSize(0.5)
        strategy.entry(id="+", long=false, qty = positionSize)
    else if c011
        positionSize := f_positionSize(1.0)
        strategy.entry(id="+", long=false, qty = positionSize)
    else if c111
        positionSize := f_positionSize(1.0)
        strategy.entry(id="+", long=true, qty = positionSize)
else
    strategy.close_all()

// For debugging.
plot(positionSize, "Position size", color.orange, 2, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write the code properly. I already learned quite a bunch just from reading it. I still have a few clarifications for a few things.

Line 35: "f_changeIn(_cond) => _cond and not _cond[1]"
What is the meaning of the operator "=>", is "_cond" a built-in variable that acts as a title for the 6 possibilities? 

Line 44:" f_positionSize(_percentEquity) => strategy.equity * _percentEquity / close"
I think the expression after the "=>" calculates the number of contracts bought/sold for one of the 6 conditions but I dont understand the expression before the =>

Comment: Line 50: "positionSize := f_positionSize(1.0)"
im not sure what the := operator does.

Comment: `=>` defines a function, which is how you define a piece of code that can be reused elsewhere. See the [usrman page on functions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Declaring_functions.html). `_cond` acts like a generic name for the actual argument passed to the function when it's called from elsewhere in the code. So when `f_changeIn(s000)` is invoked later in the code, `_cond` is replaced with `s000`. The `:=` is the assignment operator, which is used to assign a value to a variable that has already been declared.

Comment: Ok so I got more familiar since the last time. I have a problem so I'm back-testing with BTC but for some reason depending on whether I put a condition as a long or short position Pinescript won't execute some of the orders when there is a condition change. Although it works with the JPYUSD as you did, with lots of other securities there isn't even a single trade executed such as with the SPX. Is this a problem with the code or is Pinescript buggy?